# Hosting cell with Swift UI cell views are overlapping on scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swiftui, uikit

I am trying to add a SwiftUI view as a cell view using a hosting cell. I am setting `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for the height of the cell.

During the scroll, the cells overlaps.

My understanding is that it could be due to the deque. Is there a way to handle this?

Can anyone please help?

```
  private func cellView(_ index: Int) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let filterCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HostingCell<CellView>") as? HostingCell<CellView>,
              let viewModel = viewModel.data else {
            return HostingCell<cellView>()
        }
        let cellViewModel = viewModel.viewModelForRadioButton(at: index, theme: theme)
        filterCell.set(rootView: FilterCellView(viewModel: cellViewModel, isSelected: viewModel.selectedIndex() == index), parentController: self)
        return filterCell
    }
```

---

```
class HostingCell <Content: View>: UITableViewCell {

private let hostingController = UIHostingController<Content?>(rootView: nil)

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func set(rootView: Content,
         parentController: UIViewController,
         hostingControllerBackground: UIColor? = nil) {
    self.hostingController.rootView = rootView
    self.hostingController.view.backgroundColor = hostingControllerBackground
    self.hostingController.view.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()

    let requiresControllerMove = hostingController.parent != parentController
    if requiresControllerMove {
        parentController.addChild(hostingController)
    }

    if !self.contentView.subviews.contains(hostingController.view) {
        self.contentView.addSubview(hostingController.view)
        hostingController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        hostingController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        hostingController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        hostingController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        hostingController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    if requiresControllerMove {
        hostingController.didMove(toParent: parentController)
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are issues with constraints when SwiftUI and UIKit work together.

I don't have the right solution to it. But try giving hostingController.view.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical). Also UIHostingConfiguration will also helps if we support iOS 16+ :)

Also found some related answers
[How to use a SwiftUI view in place of table view cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57616494/how-to-use-a-swiftui-view-in-place-of-table-view-cell)